# Error: 'JSON' is undefined in IE 7

Tags: json, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8, internet-explorer-7

Um getting an Error haying Error JSON undefined in IE 7 I have included the JSON2 library as follows

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/2-0/javascript/flowplayer-3.2.6.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/2-0/javascript/jquery-impromptu.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/2-0/javascript/iscroll.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/2-0/javascript/json_parse.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/2-0/javascript/json2.js"></script>
```

But um still getting the error on this line in IE 7

```
data_array = JSON.parse(data)
```

How to fix this issue

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `JSON` object and related `JSON.parse()` and `JSON.stringify()` methods are only available for ([reference](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON#Native_encoding_and_decoding_in_browsers)):

- Firefox 3.5+
- IE 8+
- Opera 10.5+
- Webkit based (Chrome / Safari)

There is no native support for `JSON` object in legacy browsers like IE7.

You could enable it through including the `json2.js` created by Douglas [here](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js)